# Can't hide my login form after successful login

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a login form created in JavaFX and after successful login it should be hidden ,
I'm following the code that used to hide the form after sucessful login from this video but not working for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeK9DfXG5Tg
basically this is the code `((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();`

the problem I don't get any error to know what is the issue ?

this is may `Main` class

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = 
    (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fx/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,310,180);      
     scene.getStylesheets().
       add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

my controller class

```
public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private TextField Usernamefield;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField Passwordfield;

    @FXML
    public void  LoginButtonHandler(ActionEvent event){

        String UserName = Usernamefield.getText().trim();
        String PassWord = Passwordfield.getText().trim();
        Session session = 
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            String hql =" from User where Username=:UserName and Password=:PassWord";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("UserName",UserName);
            query.setParameter("PassWord",PassWord);
            List ResultSet = query.getResultList();

            if (ResultSet.size()==1){

                SessionInfo sessioninfo = new SessionInfo();
                sessioninfo.setUsername(UserName);
                System.out.println("welcome "+ sessioninfo.getUsername());
                System.out.println("opening dashboard");
                /*****************************************************
                 * openining dashboard after user logged successfully* 
                 *****************************************************/
                try{

               ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
                    FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DashBoard.fxml"));
                    BorderPane root = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    //stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    stage.setTitle("Welcome "+sessioninfo.getUsername());
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                    stage.show();
                  } catch(Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                      }


            }else
                {
                System.out.println("login faild");
            }
            System.out.println("current session statics"+session.getStatistics());
            System.out.println(Usernamefield.getText());
            System.out.println(Passwordfield.getText());
            System.out.println("transaction status 
            :"+session.getTransaction().getStatus());
            System.out.println("result size is :"+ResultSet.size());


        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (session.getTransaction() != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
            System.out.println("session is closed");
        }


    }
}
```

my `FXML`

```xml
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
 xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
 fx:controller="fx.LoginController">
     <center>
      <GridPane minHeight="172.0" minWidth="300.0" prefHeight="172.0" 
     prefWidth="326.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="228.0" 
     minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="65.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="406.0" 
     minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="261.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" 
     vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" 
     vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" 
     vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
         <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0" pickOnBounds="true" 
         preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../resource/images/User-40.png" />
               </image>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="40.0" 
         pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../resource/images/Lock-40.png" />
               </image>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </ImageView>
            <PasswordField fx:id="Password" promptText="password" 
         GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </PasswordField>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Login" text="Login" 
         GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="190.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <TextField fx:id="Username" promptText="username" 
         GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></TextField>
         </children>

           <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
          </GridPane>
         </center>
         <top>
          <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Air Book" 
          BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
          </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the conrrect method name for the handler in the fxml. Since the name of the method is `LoginButtonHandler`, The correct value for the `onAction` attribute of the `<Button>` element is `#LoginButtonHandler`:

```xml
<Button mnemonicParsing="false"
        onAction="#LoginButtonHandler"
        text="Login" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2">
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets left="190.0" />
    </GridPane.margin>
</Button>
```